# Flutter : getting single word from Text Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, textselection

I am trying to develop an app using Flutter that shows the user the translation of a single word. So if a user wants the translation of a word then he should double tap on that word and it shows him/her the translation.

Here I just don't want to get the `String` value of a `Text` Widget but I also want to get the word that the user double tapped on. So is there any way to do this?

Comment: Image example of the selected text will help clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `RichText`. In my example, if you double tap any of highlighted words, it will be printed.

[image: 1]

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final testString = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.';
  final textSpans = <TextSpan>[];

  testString.splitMapJoin(
    RegExp('\\w+'), 
    onMatch: (m) {
      final matchStr = m.group(0);

      textSpans.add(TextSpan(
        recognizer: DoubleTapGestureRecognizer()..onDoubleTap = () => print(matchStr),
        text: matchStr,
        style: TextStyle(background: Paint()..color = Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.4))
      ));
      return matchStr;
    },
    onNonMatch: (string) {
      textSpans.add(TextSpan(
        text: string,
      ));
      return string;
    },
  );

  return RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
      children: textSpans,
    ),
  );
}
```